# How do I handle a category object in django models and forms?

Tags: python, django

I have a model for, let's say, Items. These can be any sort of physical items, and they're created using a form via a POST request. During that creation, I want to attach one of a limited number of category choices to each item. There can only be one category per item.

Thus I believe each Item should have a foreignkey to a Category (many-to-one relationship). That seems simple enough. But when I try to implement it via the two models and a ModelForm, the category choices don't display. I'm thinking that I don't actually have any Category instances in the database, and thus can't grab them to associate with the Items. Should I check for a given category's existence when I process the POST, then create it if necessary, then associate it with the Item? Or would it be better to manually create the Category instances in the database?

Here's what I have in .models (I'm paring everything down for simplicity's sake):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items")

class Category(models.Model):
    PERSON = 'PE'
    PLACE = 'PL'
    THING = 'TH'

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        (PERSON, 'Person'),
        (PLACE, 'Place'),
        (THING, 'Thing'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=PERSON)
```

Here's .forms:

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name', 'category']
        labels = {
            'name': _('Item name'),
        }
        {
            'category': _('What category does it fall under?'),
        }
```

Basically I feel like I'm missing an important step somewhere in the category creation, but am having trouble pinpointing how and where to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your category field inside your Item model like

```
class Item(models.Model):
    PERSON = 'PE'
    PLACE = 'PL'
    THING = 'TH'

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        (PERSON, 'Person'),
        (PLACE, 'Place'),
        (THING, 'Thing'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=PERSON)

class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name', 'category']
        labels = {
            'name': _('Item name'),
            'category': _('What category does it fall under?'),
        }
```

Comment: Ah, so essentially don't have a separate class for it. Guess that makes sense in this case. I was thinking having the related_name was important but if I needed to look up by category I could just do a normal database lookup on the Item attribute.